# How many stereoisomers of octahydroquinoline are there?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, heterocyclic-compounds

I am trying to work out how many stereoisomers there could be of the following.

[image: 2,3,4,4a,5,6,7,8-octahydroquinoline]

As indicated, I think there are two sites of varying the stereochemistry. The top site can have the hydrogen in different positions. However, can the bottom site be changed? I don't own a model set and so I am really struggling to see this!

Comment: The bottom site is connected to a double bond, so I wouldn't think it could be a chiral center since it only has three groups around it.

Comment: So I only have two stereoisomers (which are enantiomers)?

Comment: That would be my understanding, since it looks to me that it only has one chiral carbon.